# Error occurred while mounting /boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I wanted to remove Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 from my laptop and just create one partition for Ubuntu 14.04, but this seems to be more difficult then I thought it would be.

Installation seems to go perfect, but the first time I boot my PC I get a black rectangle with a small border of a few pixels in an other color (I think the computer is trying to load GRUB). The second time I try to boot GRUB appears. But then I get a screen with an error: `An error occurred while mounting /boot. Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery`. I have already tried a few things like formatting the whole disk and reinstalling, but this gives the same problem.

`grep boot /etc/fstab` gives:

```
/boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=8f1dc104-1ba0-4783-9b16-4302e24855ce /boot ext2 defaults 0 2
```

`blkid | grep ext` gives:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="8f1dc104-1ba0-4783-9b16-4302e24855ce" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ex4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="32787824-e81d-4a6a-92b5-ba7ca2ac6875" TYPE="ext4"
```

I used the boot repair program which I found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and I still got the same problem. The output of the program is this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7750787/

All extra input about in which direction I need to seek is more then welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this answer is probably too late for you...

It sounds like something is preventing `/boot` from mounting.  But the system is presumably managing to boot the kernel from it, so it isn't fatally damaged.

Commands like these might tell you more about the state of the partition:

```
sudo file -s /dev/sda1           # basic "file type" detection
sudo fsck -n /dev/sda1           # read-only filesystem check
sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda1 /boot # read-only mount test
dmesg | tail                     # should tell you what went wrong with the mount
```

If there is any sign of an error, you might find you can fix it by running `fsck /dev/sda1` and allowing it to fix any errors.